# Installing NodeAdmin for Node.JS on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I'm a seasoned developer in using the LAMP stack and am trying to switch over to Node.js and play around with it. For database management, I love the flexibility and ease of PHPmyadmin and found the NPM package NodeAdmin to be exactly what I"m looking for in terms of an analogue.

But when trying to install and access nodeadmin, the instructions look like complete Greek to me as someone coming from the Apache environment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodeadmin

I ran

```
npm install nodeadmin
```

inside the root directory and all looked good. But now I'm unable to access nodeadmin under mydomain.com/nodeadmin as it says I should in the instructions. What directory should I be installing nodeadmin in? What the heck do I do with the code in the "Setup" section of that tutorial?

Thanks in advance for helping break in a newb to his new environment.

Comment: Did you remember to add the middleware to your express app? Posting the code where you set up express/routes/middleware will help.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what it means to "add the middleware to my express app"... I'm completely new to this. I'm in my /html directory and have run `npm init` to create a project with index.js as the entry point. I've also installed express.js and added it as a dependency. Now what?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like nodeadmin is meant to be run as express middleware. The most basic set up would be to create a new file, let's call it app.js. The content of app.js should be:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var nodeadmin = require('nodeadmin');
app.use(nodeadmin(app)); //here is where you add the middleware

app.listen(80);
```

After that, go to directory where you created app.js and run the following commands

```
npm install express
npm install nodeadmin
node app.js
```

Comment: I was having the same problem. I am also a nodejs newbie. Whatever I do, I'm always finding this error:

    `Error: Cannot find module './HomeController' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)`

Any clue about what can be the problem?

Comment: @MariaVilaró You might consider posting a new question. This one was about installing. Sounds like you got it installed and now have a new problem.

Comment: I think I found the problem in nodeadmin github issues, looks like some problem about camelCase and lowercase/uppercase incoherence but I didn't have the time to check the fix yet

Answer (score 1):

It looks like nodeadmin is [express middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html), so you don't install it standalone. Instead you include the middleware in your website application and then access it via the same host on the `/nodeadmin` path.

I guess it uses the mysql config from your app to connect to the same db so you can use it to manage the application data.

```
var nodeadmin = require('nodeadmin');
app.use(nodeadmin(app));
```

[express](http://expressjs.com/) is a web framework for building nodejs apps. The nodeadmin module you're using can only be used as part of an express application. You'll need to use something else if you want to run it standalone.

A quick google turns up [Express Admin](http://simov.github.io/express-admin/). Looks like it's built using express, but doesn't need to be installed as part of an express app. You could give that a try. There may be better alternatives

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting more errors after following the above answers and am giving up and installing PHPmyadmin (which I realize I should have done from the beginning). Thanks for the answers.